# Array not resolving value

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
let startDate = moment('2016-01-01');
let endDate = moment('2016-01-12');

 for (let m = moment(startDate); m.isBefore(endDate); m.add(1, 'days')) {
       let queryDate = m.format('DD MMM YYYY');
        console.log(queryDate);

       queries.push(function (callback) {
       processMeterreadings("{ 'params': { 'path': { 'mpan': '2198765119780' },'querystring': {'startdate': '" + queryDate.toString() +  " 00:00','enddate': '" + queryDate.toString() + " 23:30','readtype': 'all'}}}",callback);
}
);

}

queries.forEach(function(data){
     console.log(data.toString());
})
```

The values being returned for the last foreach are all the same

```
function (callback) {
    processMeterreadings("{ 'params': { 'path': { 'mpan': '2198765119780' },'querystring': {'startdate': '" + queryDate.toString() +  " 00:00','enddate': '" + queryDate.toString() + " 23:30','readtype': 'all'}}}",callback);
}
```

i would expect the value of the date to be in the item in the array not the variable name.

How do i change it so the item in the array has  2016-01-02 in place of queryDate.toString()?

Comment: What's currently being output vs. what you're expecting to see?

Comment: You're going to have to explain this better. Why are you pushing a function to what we can assume is an array (`queries`), and what does that function do, and where do you call it. It actually looks like you're not calling it at all, and `toString()` is just outputting the string representation of the function you pushed to the array.

Comment: Do you want to add to the *queries* array the result of the function *processMeterreadings*?

Comment: Why don't you just push the dates you require to your array, then loop over them to process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are pushing functions into the array, but those functions are never executed. In order to evaluate the string concatenation in the function body, the functions must actually be executed.

Considering building the string *outside* of the function where the code actually executes, as opposed to pushing the unexecuted code into your array.

You can also build an object literal and use `JSON.stringify` to handle turning it into JSON for you:

```
let startDate = moment('2016-01-01');
let endDate = moment('2016-01-12');

for (let m = moment(startDate); m.isBefore(endDate); m.add(1, 'days')) {
  let queryDate = m.format('DD MMM YYYY');
  console.log(queryDate);

  let json = JSON.stringify({
    params: {
      path: {
        mpan: '2198765119780'
      },
      querystring: {
        startdate: queryDate.toString() +  ' 00:00',
        enddate: queryDate.toString() + ' 23:30',
        readtype: 'all'
      }
    }
  })

  queries.push(function (callback) {
    processMeterreadings(json)
  });
}
```

Alternatively (and preferably), don't build the JSON so early. Just store the date ranges in your array, and iterate over them when you're actually ready to perform the query:

```
let startDate = moment('2016-01-01');
let endDate = moment('2016-01-12');

for (let m = moment(startDate); m.isBefore(endDate); m.add(1, 'days')) {
  let queryDate = m.format('DD MMM YYYY');
  queries.push(queryDate);
}

queries.forEach(function(queryDate) {
  processMeterreadings(JSON.stringify({
    params: {
      path: {
        mpan: '2198765119780'
      },
      querystring: {
        startdate: queryDate.toString() +  ' 00:00',
        enddate: queryDate.toString() + ' 23:30',
        readtype: 'all'
      }
    }
  }));
});
```